# Python - Dataframe column update with a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, lookup

I've a pandas dataframe (server_df) with columns as below,

```
Sever_Name, ID, Scan success date
Windows123, karthik, 24-Aug-2020
Windows123, jk, 23-Aug-2020
Windows123, yuvi, 11-Jul-2020
```

**Need a new column in the dataframe with below conditions:**

If(or(scan success date = vlookup(server_name,range,3,0),(vlookup(server_name,range,3,0)-scan success date)<3)), "updated results","deleted account")

I formulated above one based on excel conditions, not sure how to achieve this in Python data frame. Please help!!

Comment: Please explain the condition in the IF

Comment: or give example

Comment: Thanks. Basically my data have deleted accounts in a server and i need to find them based on the scan success date. I already sort the dataframe with newest to oldest scan date. Now, the latest scan date comes first and need to compare this with second account scan date. If the difference between this two dates are less than 3 then, it is not a deleted account else can flag the account as deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the condition, but the solution should be based on:

```
import numpy as np
server_df['result'] = np.where(<condition>, "updated results","deleted account")
```

Comment: I finally wrote this code, can this be added in the condition or any simple way to do the below?                             temp_df = server_df['server_name','scan success date']; temp_df = temp_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['server_name']); server_df = server_df.merge(temp_df,on=('server_name'),suffixes=('_l','_r')); server_df['Day diff'] = (server_df['scan success date_r'] - server_df['scan success date_l']).Dt.days; server_df['result'] = server_df['Day diff'].Apply(lambda x: 'Updated Result' if x <= 2 else 'Deleted Account')

Comment: You can do that using a lambda function